# in a windows drivers what does the device type FILE_DEVICE_VIRTUAL_DISK means?

Tags: windows, drivers

I am looking on specific documentation on FILE_DEVICE_VIRTUAL_DISK,
what does it implies on IO when you are using a ramdisk ?

Does it implies no os caching ?

Here is the reference on msdn on the driver types

searching FILE_DEVICE_VIRTUAL_DISK in google does not help a lot

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ff563821(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: In this old [ramdisk.sys sample](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/257405), it creates the device as a `FILE_DEVICE_VIRTUAL_DISK`. Note under "Windows XP Update" that it's recommended to change this to `FILE_DEVICE_DISK` so it can be formatted. The current [RAMDisk sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/RAMDisk-Storage-Driver-9ce5f699) uses `FILE_DEVICE_DISK` in `RamDiskEvtDeviceAdd`.